# Group if-else statement then execute a random set

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, random, python-3.6

I'm making a program that will generate a random trivia quiz, which, in each question contain if-else statement and variables. Need to know how can I group each set and generate a random set each time, with *import random* or please suggest me if there's another way to do this.

my code:

```
c1 = 0
c2 = 0
while(1):
  quiz1 = print("What is Prosciutto?")
  q = input().lower()
  if ("italian" in q) or ("dry" in q) or ("ham" in q):
    print("Correct!")
    c1 +=1
  else:
    print("Not quiet right, Prosciutto is Italian dry-cured ham")
    c2 +=1
  input("Press Enter to continue...")
  quiz2 = print("What is the capital of the US state of Alabama?")
  q = input().lower()
  if "montgomery" in q:
    print("Correct!")
    c1 +=1
  else:
    print("Nope, Montgomery, it is.")
    c2 +=1
  input("Press Enter to continue...")
  quiz3 = print("Which planet spins on a nearly horizontal axis?")
  q = input().lower()
  if "uranus" in q:
    print("Correct!")
    c1 +=1
  else:
    print("Actually it is Uranus!")
    c2 +=1
  input("Press Enter to continue...")
  quiz4 = print("Who invented writing?")
  q = input().lower()
  if "sumerian" in q:
    print("Correct!")
    c1 +=1
  else:
    print("Nope, the Sumerians invented writing")
    c2 +=1
  input("Press Enter to continue...")
  quiz5 = print("What rapper was born Marshall Bruce Mathers III?")
  q = input().lower()
  if "eminem" in q:
    print("Correct!")
    c1 +=1
  else:
    print("He's Eminem")
    c2 +=1
  input("Trivia ended, Press Enter to view your result...")
  break
print("You've made", c1, "corrects answers and ", c2, "wrong answers")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First factor out the recurrent "ask a question and check answer" pattern:

```
def handle(question, answer, err):
    print(question)
    a = input().lower()
    if a in answer:
        print("Correct!")
        return True
    else:
        print(err)
        return False
```

Then define your questions/answers/err :

```
QUIZZES = [
    ("What is Prosciutto?", ("italian","cured","dryed","ham"), "Not quiet right, Prosciutto is Italian dry-cured ham"),
    ("What is the capital of the US state of Alabama?", ("montgomery",), "Nope, Montgomery, it is."),
    # etc
    ]
```

Then you just need a main function to run the whole thing:

```
def main():
    good = 0
    wrong = 0   
    for question, answers, err in QUIZZES:
        ok = handle(question, answers, err)
        if ok:
            good += 1
        else:
            wrong += 1
    input("Trivia ended, Press Enter to view your result...")
    print("You've made {} corrects answers and  {} wrong answers".format(good, wrong))
```

Once you're there, adding randomisation is only a matter of calling `random.choice()` on `QUIZZES`...

Comment: I tried it, but it printed a whole set of question, like *('What is the capital of the US state of Alabama?', 'montgomery', 'Nope, Montgomery, it is.')* instead of a question only, then it ran the trivia in order again. I used `import random` by the way.

Comment: It worked now, after replacing `for question, answers, err in QUIZZES:` with `while(1): question,answers,err = random.choice(QUIZZES)`, thanks for help.

Comment: You might want to keep track of already asked questions to avoid repeating the same quizz over and over again (hint: use a `set` to store asked questions in your while loop)

Comment: Thank you :) though, do you think it will take long time to process if it runs through small amount of quizzes? I guess there's higher chance that the quiz in the set will repeat on itself, unless I have, like 100 quizzes...

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "take long time to process" ?

Comment: Like, many execution in the background, because it keep repeating until it can find the quiz that's not the same...?

Comment: It should be fast enough really... There are more subtle algorithms like using a copy of the quizzes list and poping quizzes from it at random indices (using `random.randrange(len(quizzes)+1)` to get the indice) until it's empty, but I'm not sure it will be faster nor more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary with key = question and value = answers , also make a list of all the questions. then import random and randint a number between 0 and len(question_list) and display the user that question - and check if his answer is the value in the dictionary where the key is the given question . just from the top of my head